# Programmatically detecting unpackaged metadata in org that depends on my package

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, tooling-api, cpulimit

My managed package is extensively customized and extended by some customers in their org. For our packaged objects they e.g. add

1. Triggers + Custom Apex code
2. Fields
3. Validation Rules
4. Workflows
5. Process Builder processes

I learned the hard way how such customizations can degrade packaged functionality (perfectly described [in this Dreamforce session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6QnalRWlEE)). To better know how much customization there is I planned on displaying this info on a page to the customer. My question now is:

**How can I use the Metadata / Tooling API to find dependencies of my packaged objects?**

Some of these informations can be queried using a SOQL on ApexPage, ApexTrigger and others, but is there a way for all the other relevant metadata types?

Comment: I'm not *sure* if this is possible, but maybe you could try a destructiveChanges.xml deploy + validation only flag, then you'd get a list of errors?

Comment: Salesforce launched a Pilot for dependency API.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_metadata_metadatacomponentdependency.htm
Let's hope soon we won't have to put in kludges with a destructive changes :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use listMetadata() to quickly get the names of various components by type. You will have to search for your package namespace prefix in the returned names to see the unpackaged customizations.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm

The problem with this method is that there will be uncertainty as to where the customizations might reside, and there are 200 metadata types. But it sounds like you have an idea where to look.

Also, you can experiment with the new metadataComponentDependency() tooling API. This will allow you to look instead at your packaged objects and see the dependencies.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm